# one label for two-lane roads (osm, qgis, postgis)

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, labeling, qgis-3

I labeled my osm-lines-layer (PostGIS) with symbols for primary roads and motorways. While the symbols for the primary roads are well placed - with enough distance between each - the two-lane motorway is labeled with one label per lane (as you can see in the image).

Is it possible, to set something like a radius from each label, within no other label of the same type can be placed? Or can I just say: label one lane of a two-lane road?

I'm using qgis. The OSM-Data is imported to PostGIS with osm2pgsql.

[image]

EDIT:This new screenshot shows more detail:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To label only one lane of a two-lane road I'm using the expression:

```
 angle_at_vertex($geometry,1) <= 180
```

and use it as filter. This works because in OSM each lane is drawn in their direction.

*In the example below I'm using the expression `angle_at_vertex($geometry,1)` as label and in the second picture the expression `angle_at_vertex($geometry,1) <= 180` as filter.*

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

[Settings](https://github.com/MrXsquared/OSM-Geofabrik_Universal-QML-Style/blob/master/Styles/gis_osm_roads_free_1.qml):

[image]

Comment: Now that's one clever little trick. +1 also for the QML file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the schema of the OSM tables, but you asked for a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM labels WHERE label_id  IN (
    SELECT label_id_2 FROM (
        SELECT a.label_id AS label_id_1, b.label_id AS label_id_2 
        FROM labels AS a, labels AS b WHERE STDWithin(a.the_geom,b.the_geom, 0.001) and a.street = b.street and a.label_id != b.label_id
    )
)
```

This may work but It would be better if you have an id for the same label for different directions, and then this query would work 100%:

```
DELETE FROM labels WHERE label_id  IN (
    SELECT label_id_2 FROM (
        SELECT a.label_id AS label_id_1, b.label_id AS label_id_2 
        FROM labels AS a, labels AS b WHERE a.same_road_label_id = b.same_road_label_id;
    )
)
```

Comment: Looks fine, but Im not familiar with sql-programming. So, could you please explain what "a.label_id", "a.label_id_1" and so on stands for? My table has a ID (column osm_id) and a column (ref) for the label (for example "A70").

Comment: I've nicknamed labels table as "a" and "b", and label_id column(osm_id) as label_id_1 and label_id_2 with the "AS" statement, I had to because in the deepest subquery we have two columns(label_id) and two tables(labels) with the same name.